# ansible: Extract value from the register variables to use it in other plays within same playbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-vpc

I'm setting up complete environment using ansible. For some reason, ansible is not picking up variable values.

I'm using ansible 2.1.1.0

Here's a strip example of what I'm trying to do:
I have registered my vpc with `register: ec2_vpc`.

```
1. #This didn't works
    - name: Add to host vars
      add_host:
            name: vpc_vars
            groups: vpc_subnets
            vpc_subnet_id: "{{ ec2_vpc.subnets[0].id }}"
            vpcid: "{{ ec2_vpc.vpc_id }}"
    - debug: var=vpc_subnet_id
    - debug: var=vpcid

2. These works
    - name: Record vpc id
      debug: var=ec2_vpc.vpc_id

    - name: Record subnet id
      debug: var=ec2_vpc.subnets[0].id
```

Resulted json of my above strip:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "vpc_subnet_id": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "vpcid": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

TASK [Record vpc id] ***********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ec2_vpc.vpc_id": "vpc-4sdh3832f"
}

TASK [Record subnet id] ********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ec2_vpc.subnets[0].id": "subnet-edfjdh3482"
}
```

Why is my first syntax not picking the value instead its giving `VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!`

**Updated:** Here my 2nd syntax describes I am correctly sorting out the value from the JSON result of registered variable. But I want it work for my 1st syntax which means I want to add hosts variables to dynamic inventory. So that I can reuse it in another play

Comment: First syntax doesn't work because you add variables to new host with name `vpc subnets` and group name `vpc_vars` (what for?)... If you run subsequent plays against `vpc_vars` group, your variables will be visible. I can't understand what do you try to achieve with all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_host` dynamically adds host to your inventory.
I guess you just need `set_fact`:

```
- name: Add to host vars
  set_fact:
        vpc_subnet_id: "{{ ec2_vpc.subnets[0].id }}"
        vpcid: "{{ ec2_vpc.vpc_id }}"
- debug: var=vpc_subnet_id
- debug: var=vpcid
```

Comment: Yes I want to add  host dynamically  to inventory. So that I can reuse it in another play. `set_fact`  does save in variables I assigned with. It will be good if I save it in dynamic host inventory

Comment: You'd better describe your task in the question itself. `set_fact` and `add_host` are for different purposes. You can always access variable of other hosts via `hostvars` variable.

Comment: `hostvars` helps me in the way I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you said that you have register your return value/result in `ec2_vpc` then how you can get it `vpc_subnet_id` or `vpcid`. you want to get it through this then you have to do like this:

```
- set_fact:
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ ec2_vpc.subnets[0].id }}"
    vpcid: "{{ ec2_vpc.vpc_id }}"
```

Hope that help you.

Comment: I am trying to store my results in the variables `vpc_subnet_id` or `vpcid`. So that I can reuse in another play.

Comment: The other thing I can suggest you to save the values in file and then include it dynamically